how can I create a delay for text to disappear after showing up? processing java
void drawMessage() {
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(64);
  fill(255); // White for "Pokemon"
  text("Pokemon", width / 2, height / 2 - 40);
  fill(color(255, 165, 0)); // Orange for "Orange"
  text("Orange", width / 2, height / 2 + 40);

  messageAnimating = false;
  fill(0);
  rect(0, blackboxtopy, width, 1020);
  rect(0, blackboxbottomy, width, 1020);
  
}

I'm making a pokemon game for a school final computer science project. I'm trying to get the text to show up, then go away after 5 seconds. How would I do that?
I've tried using for loops, but that didn't work. I've also tried using the delay() function, but that bugged it out so that the text didn't display at all.

Try using frameCount or millis() instead of delay(). (If the CS project allows the use of libraries you can also checkout the Ani library.). Good luck!
